# How to collect content from articles in USA Today newspaper using Beautifulsoup in Python 3.7?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-3.7

I am collecting date, headline, and content from USA Today Newspaper. I can able to get Date, headline and even content but along with content, I am getting some unwanted stuff. I don't know what I should change in my code to get only the content (article)?

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Tag

url = 'https://www.usatoday.com/search/?q=cybersecurity&page={}'
pages = 72

for page in range(1, pages+1):
    res = requests.get(url.format(page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")

    for item in soup.find_all("a", {"class": "gnt_se_a"}, href=True):
        _href = item.get("href")
        try:
            resp = requests.get(_href)
        except Exception as e:
            try:
                resp = requests.get("https://www.usatoday.com"+_href)
            except Exception as e:
                continue

        sauce = BeautifulSoup(resp.text,"lxml")
        dateTag = sauce.find("span",{"class": "asset-metabar-time asset-metabar-item nobyline"})
        titleTag = sauce.find("h1", {"class": "asset-headline speakable-headline"})
        contentTag = sauce.find("div", {"class": "asset-double-wide double-wide p402_premium"})

        date = None
        title = None
        content = None

        if isinstance(dateTag,Tag):
            date = dateTag.get_text().strip()

        if isinstance(titleTag,Tag):
            title = titleTag.get_text().strip()

        if isinstance(contentTag,Tag):
            content = contentTag.get_text().strip()

        print(f'{date}\n {title}\n {content}\n')

        time.sleep(3)
```

I am expecting date, headline, and content from each article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to find content by

```
contentTag = sauce.find_all('p',{"class": "p-text"})
```

and condition for content is

```
if isinstance(contentTag,list):
    content = []
    for c in contentTag:
        content.append(c.get_text().strip())
    content = ' '.join(content)
```

It works.